# PEP8 inspection in PyCharm not working with Docker remote python interpreter

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker, pycharm, pep8

I use local python interpreter, pep8 work well and I see all warnings in my files.
Then I switch to remote python interpreter from Docker, all warnings disappeared.

Python on local and Docker: 2.7.12
Pycharm: PyCharm 2017.3.3 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-173.4301.16, built on January 11, 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-12325/PEP8-highlighting-not-working-in-PyCharm), Pycharm needs a local interpreter in order to inspect the code. For me, the following worked:

- Create a new (dummy) project
- Configure a **local** Python interpreter for the dummy project
- Close Pycharm
- Open Pycharm and then open your original project that uses the remote interpreter
- PEP8 inspection works! (granted that it is enabled in the settings)

Basically my understanding is that it needs a local interpreter to be configured for some project but not necessarily for the specific project you want to run the inspection on.